# Does a framework exist for Mobile website development with native look and feel for Android, iPhone and other smartphones?

Tags: smartphone

As far as i know for native application development is done using

- PhoneGap
- Titanium

Do we have a framework or something where we can build a mobile website where MySQL DB, HTML5 and jQuery mobile can be used. This mobile website can be accessed by different smart phones(android, iPhone, blackberry etc). This mobile website will have native look and feel.

Please help me if you have some idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

The main framework thatpop into my mind when you describe what you are looking for is [**Sensha Touch 2**](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

After some googling I think you could also have a look at [**Wink**](http://www.winktoolkit.org/) which seems to be more lightweight.